# отправка письма

Tags: android, gmail

```
 String var = "App name:"+getResources().getString(' ')+"\nApp version"+getResources().getString(' ')+"\nDevice:"+Build.DEVICE+" "+Build.MODEL+"\nAndroid"+ Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"(SDK:"+ Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+") \nYour message:";
                                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SENDTO", Uri.parse("12112@mail.ru , 123123@mail.ru"));
                                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT",getResources().getString(' ')+"-Report");
                                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT",var);
                                startActivity(intent);
```

в чем ошибка ?прога вылетает

```
       at com.gigamole.sample.screens.MainActivity$3.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:315)
                                                                           at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder$6.onClick(DrawerBuilder.java:1759)
                                                                           at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder$6.onClick(DrawerBuilder.java:1733)
```

Comment: Там действительно только 3 строчки?

Answer (score 0):

решил сделать другим методом и  все работает!

```
 private void sendUsingGmail(Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo == null) continue;
            if ("com.google.android.gm".equals(info.activityInfo.packageName)){
                intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    startActivity(emailIntent);
}

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"******@gmail.com"});
                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"******** - Support");
                                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"App name: ******"+"\nApp version: ******G"+"\nDevice: "+Build.DEVICE+" "+Build.MODEL+"\nAndroid: "+ Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"(SDK:"+ Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+") \nYour message:");
                                sendUsingGmail(emailIntent);
```